# firebase database permission denied even if my rules looks right

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making shopping app with a cart and storing cart content in database. I set rules so that the user can only read and write on his own cart.
here is my code:

```
final DatabaseReference cartListRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Carts");

        double totalprice = buyCount.getValue() * Double.parseDouble(productPrice.getText().toString());

        final HashMap<String, Object> cartMap = new HashMap<>();
        cartMap.put("id", productId);
        cartMap.put("name", productName.getText().toString());
        cartMap.put("price", productPrice.getText().toString());
        cartMap.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
        cartMap.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
        cartMap.put("quantity", Long.toString(buyCount.getValue()));
        cartMap.put("discount", "");
        cartMap.put("image", imageUrl);
        cartMap.put("totalPrice", totalprice);

        cartListRef.child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                .child("Products").child(productId)
                .updateChildren(cartMap)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(ProductDetailsActivity.this, "تمت اضافة المنتج اٍلى السلة", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                Intent intent = new Intent(ProductDetailsActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                    }
                });
```

and here are my rules:

```
{
"rules": {
  "Users": {
    "$uid": {
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
     }
   },
  "Products": {
       ".read": "auth != null",
       ".write": "auth != null"
  },
  "Carts": {
    "Users":{
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
    
  } 
     
 }
}
```

I get error permission denied:

> 10-03 18:04:06.567 14964-15226/com.cloud.fashenista W/SyncTree: Listen at /Orders/Users/lDQI2pwcuLfStHEfdC9cbfMsYf92 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied 2020-10-03 18:04:06.753 14964-15226/com.cloud.fashenista W/SyncTree: Listen at /Orders/Users/lDQI2pwcuLfStHEfdC9cbfMsYf92/Products/IVvWWSaVC5YRMZoZs9AO failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied –

I am not sure if this make any difference but there is no child named "Carts" yet

Comment: I don't immediately see how the `updateChildren ` would be rejected by the rules you shared. Can you show the complete error message and stack trace you get?

Comment: 10-03 18:04:06.567 14964-15226/com.cloud.fashenista W/SyncTree: Listen at /Orders/Users/lDQI2pwcuLfStHEfdC9cbfMsYf92 failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
2020-10-03 18:04:06.753 14964-15226/com.cloud.fashenista W/SyncTree: Listen at /Orders/Users/lDQI2pwcuLfStHEfdC9cbfMsYf92/Products/IVvWWSaVC5YRMZoZs9AO failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Comment: The error message is for a **listen** (so: read) operation, for which you didn't share the code. You'll want to check your code for listeners at `/Orders/Users/$uid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message shows that you're trying to **read** the data at `/Orders/Users/lDQI2pwcuLfStHEfdC9cbfMsYf92`, for which no rules are defined - so that read is rejected.

You'll want to update your security rules to also allow the user to read their orders:

```
{
"rules": {
  ...
  "Orders": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  },
}
```